# How can integrate login form of YII user module in layout/main.php

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

### How can integrate login form of YII user module in layout/main.php

I would like to know how can use login form and registration form in Yii user module into layouts/main.php like facebook index page.If anyone can please give me the details..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you using bootstrap or simple Cmenu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a widget. Here's a short crash course on making a widget:

1. Create `LoginFormWidget.php` here: `/protected/components/LoginFormWidget.php`
2. Create the view folder for your widgets here `/protected/components/views/`
3. Create the view file for your `LoginFormWidget`, like so: `/protected/components/views/loginFormWidget.php`
4. Put the following code in your `LoginFormWidget.php` file:

   ```
   class LoginFormWidget extends CWidget
   {
       /**
        * Is called when $this->beginWidget() is called
        */
       public function init()
       {

       }

       /**
        * Is called when $this->endWidget() is called
        */
       public function run()
       {
           $model = new LoginForm;
           $this->render('loginFormWidget', array('model'=>$model));
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add teh view file, make sure that you specify which action will be used:

   ```
   <div class="form"> 
       <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
           'id'=>'login-form',
           'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
           'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
           'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'customClass'),
           'action' => array('site/login'), // this is is the action that's going to process the data
       )); ?>

           <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
           <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
           <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>

           <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
           <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
           <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>

           <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Log in!'); ?>

       <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
   </div>
   ```
6. Finally, call the widget in your `main.php` file, like so:

`<?php $this->widget('LoginFormWidget'); ?>`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks bro.and one more question-Can i do this for include registration form in main

Comment: yeah you can do this for almost any functionality that you would usually do with a controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate login form then you use that in your Cmenu. You can also make a widget for that but you can also render form. If you want to render form then you can do like this

```
$form=$this->renderPartial('loginForm');
```

Now in your Cmenu widget you have to change the property `'encodeLable'` to `false` like

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
             'encodeLabel'=>false,
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>$form, 'url'=>array('site/index')),
    ),
));
```